# Creating an ASP .NET User Authentication Connection String using VMWare Fusion with OS Windows 7 on a MAC

Tags: asp.net, macos, sql-server-express

I am attempting to create an ASP .NET User Authentication provider on a MAC using VMWare Fusion installed with Windows 7. I have created the SQLExpress datatbase named CustomerOrders, and have a connection to the DB in Server Explorer within Visual Studio 2010.

When I try to use the Web Site Administration tool I receive this error:
The connection name 'ApplicationServices' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty. (\vmware-host\shared folders\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\CustomerOrders\CustomerOrders\web.config)

What I can’t figure out is the connection string I need to use in the Web.Config in order to setup the ASP .NET Authentication provider for this project running in a VMWare Fusion environment.

The connection string to my local database is:
 Data Source=WIN-NOABML9MSVB\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=CustomerOrders;Integrated Security=True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you have the [connection string specified in your web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233.aspx):

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ApplicationServices" 
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerOrders;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

(Notice that I use .\SQLEXPRESS instead of the computer name, to make sure I use the local named instance)

Then, if you haven't done so already, [make sure you create the `CustomerOrders` database and run the schema tool to create the database objects you need](http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2009/10/02/installing-asp-net-membership-services-database-in-sql-server-expreess.aspx).

Comment: Now in the Web Site Administration Tool I can test the connection and that passes but when I click on Security I'm receiving this error: There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store. 

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

Comment: My fault... I had done everything prior you mentioned but running the schema tool from the link you provided. Once the tool was finished I re-started my VMWare instance, and made a slit change to the connection string. Instead of using CustomerOrders for the Catalog I used the dbo name aspnetdb that was created after running the schema tool. Thanks for the help!